# Merge to arrays in PHP (2D)

Tags: php

i need to merge an 2d array, if possible without any loops. Is there any way to use those 2 Arrays:

```
$array1 = array(
    0 => array('LABEL' => 'Label1'),
    1 => array('LABEL' => 'Label2'),
    2 => array('LABEL' => 'Label3'),
);

$array2 = array(
    0 => array('LABEL' => 'Label1'),
    1 => array('LABEL' => 'Label2'),
    2 => array('LABEL' => 'Label4'),
);
```

and get this result:

```
$result = array(
    0 => array('LABEL' => 'Label1'),
    1 => array('LABEL' => 'Label2'),
    2 => array('LABEL' => 'Label3'),
    3 => array('LABEL' => 'Label4'),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

And if you want no double results in the array, you could use the multidimensional array save function from the PHP comments here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php#97285